# How to save NLA action but don't use it?

Tags: animation, armature, nla-editor

I'm animating something that I made using armatures. I made a very basic walk cycle, and turned it into an NLA action. However, in the current scene of the animation I'm making, I don't actually need it to walk. However, when i remove the action from the nla editor, it seems to be gone forever, and I can't find a way to get it back (apart from simply undoing the removal).

Is there any way that I can create an NLA action and save it for use later without using it? This must be a noob question...

Comment: Do you want to save the action data or the NLA track?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a `Muted` checkbox in action strip properties. While in NLA editor hit <kbd>N</kbd> and open `Active strip` scroll (see [wiki](http://www.blender.org/manual/animation/editors/nla.html#active-strip) for more info).

[image]

This exactly strip will no longer play while in animation.

Note that when `Muted` is turned on, it pauses on the current action of animation. So you might want to start animation again to make character return to his beginning position.

As another way it's possible to turn on `Animated` option in Evaluation scroll and set its value to 0.

[image]

The advantage is that the current position of character will be automatically set to beginning position when <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> pressed.